# Using IFTTT with Google Assistance and Dropbox to open Spotify with Powershell

Tags: powershell, command-prompt, ifttt

I used this code in Powershell to Open Spotify using IFTTT but I have to manually enter it and then it starts running and opens spotify when I use Google Assistant.

I use it with the Task Scheduler which in theory should run the code as soon as the PC turns on, but after many Restarts it doesnt seem to work.

```
#Declare Variables
$SearchDirectory = "C:\Users\kidwithnikon\Dropbox\IFTTT"
$SleepTime = 5

#Removes the file from the directory, in case the file was not deleted. Sets the error action in case the file is not present.
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\spotify.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Loop checking to see if the file has been created and once it has it continues on. Sleep in the look to prevent CPU pegging
Do {
Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepTime
$FileCheck = Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\spotify.txt"
}
Until ($FileCheck -eq $True)

#Removes the spotify file
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\spotify.txt"

Start-Item -Path "C:\Users\kidwithnikon\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"
```

Basically,

I have paired my Google Assistant to my Dropbox on PC

When I say "Run Spotify on PC"

the google assistant sends a .txt file called spotify to my Dropbox on the PC

which the powershell code (that should already be running) sees that its in the Dropbox and deletes the .txt file and runs the Spotify program.

Using the same code I made it so that my PC would shut down when I say "turn my PC OFF"

Following is the code for the IFTTT Automatic Shutdown

```
#Declare Variables
$SearchDirectory = "C:\Users\kidwithnikon\Dropbox\IFTTT"
$SleepTime = 5

#Removes the file from the directory, in case the file was not deleted. Sets the error action in case the file is not present.
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt" -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Loop checking to see if the file has been created and once it has it continues on. Sleep in the look to prevent CPU pegging
Do {
Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepTime
$FileCheck = Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt"
}
Until ($FileCheck -eq $True)

#Removes the shutdown file to prevent an immediate shutdown when the computer starts back up
Remove-Item -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt"

#Shuts the computer down forcefully but gracefully
Stop-Computer -Force
```

I am an ametuer in coding so please forgive me if the whole code is wrong or doesnt make sense.

I just tried to change the parameters logically and made it so it would work.

This is my First Coding Project as well.

Please Help.

I dont need Sleep, I need Answers

Comment: You could start by adding logging to your code that writes in a file what the script is doing. For example in your do-loop add `"$(get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss): looking for file..." | out-file "C:\temp\log.txt"`. When you do so, don't forget to put a `start-sleep -seconds 10` in your loop also to reduce the output.

Comment: could you send me the code, I really didnt get what you meant, I got what you said till do-loop add and then you lost me
I wasnt lying when I said i am a noob

Comment: `Do {
Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepTime
"$(get-date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss): looking for file..." | out-file "C:\temp\log.txt" -append
#$FileCheck = Test-Path -Path "$SearchDirectory\shutdown.txt"
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, you really helped me